# Schema.org for product bundles

Tags: schema.org

I have been looking at Schema.org for a while now and I was wondering whether you are able to define certain product bundles.

There are certain add-ons which allow you to sell multiple products in a bundle with a slight discount (you could call it 'buy together').

I was wondering if you can define these products in the schema. Or should you define them as a seperate `Product`?

Comment: Have a look at isRelatedTo within Products (https://schema.org/isRelatedTo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Offer`](https://schema.org/Offer) type should make this possible.

If it’s a fixed bundle, you could have one `Offer` item for multiple `Product` items. Just provide multiple values for the [`itemOffered`](https://schema.org/itemOffered) property.

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Offer",
  "itemOffered": [
    {"@type": "Product"},
    {"@type": "Product"},
    {"@type": "Product"}
  ],
  "price": "50.00"
}
```

If it’s a product for which add-ons are offered, you can use the [`addOn`](https://schema.org/addOn) property:

> An additional offer that can only be obtained in combination with the first base offer (e.g. supplements and extensions that are available for a surcharge).

Comment: @SubjectiveYetObjective: You mean for their [Products rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product)? According to their doc, they don’t make use of `addOn`, but they can make use of `itemOffered`.